# How to make class active inside a foreach statement ?

Tags: php

I have this code which lists all my categories(about 10). But I got a problem on having a class="active". Below on my code it makes all my links as active. How could I do/specify that the link must be the one to be class as active?

I know that Im in a little bit close, but I am really stuck of how could I do it. I hope again that someone could correct/lend me some help.

```
$terms = get_terms('portfolio_category');
$url = get_bloginfo('url');
$base = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$title_slug =  basename(get_permalink()) ;      

foreach ( $terms as $term) {
    $class = 'class ="active"';
    if($base ==  $title_slug){
    ?>

    <a <?php echo $class; } ?> href="<?php echo $url; ?>/portfolio/<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"> <?php  echo $term->name.'<br />'; ?> </a> 

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: what is your active class condition.

Comment: @Roopendra actually im working on wordpress, the active class condition there is the if($base == $title_slug). the $title_slug is the slug name of my post.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you should try something like this

```
foreach ( $terms as $term) {
    $class = $base ==  $title_slug ? 'class ="active"' : '';
?>
<a <?php echo $class; ?> href="<?php echo $url . '/portfolio/' . $term->slug; ?>"><?php  echo $term->name; ?></a><br />
<?php } ?>
```

Also it'll be better to replace `<?php ?>` with short tag version `<?= ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `if` statement inside `foreach`:

```
$class = $base ==  $title_slug ? 'class ="active"' : '';
if($base ==  $term->slug){
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your block of code :-

```
foreach ( $terms as $term) {
    $class = ($base ==  $title_slug) ? 'class ="active"' : '';
    ?>

    <a <?php echo $class; ?> href="<?php echo $url; ?>/portfolio/<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"> <?php  echo $term->name.'<br />'; ?> </a> 

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks it works for me but i change only the $title_slug to $term->slug, coz it works

Answer (score 0):

In my situation this one works for me. I applied what Alaa replied inside the `if` statement and it goes to what I am needed.

```
foreach ( $terms as $term) {
$class = ($base ==  $term->slug) ? 'class ="active"' : '';
?>
<a <?php  echo $class;  ?> href="<?php echo $url; ?>/portfolio/<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"> <?php  echo $term->name.'<br />' ?> </a> 
<?php } ?>
```